# How to programmatically detect which drive is used for the swap file on Windows?

Tags: windows, memory

All,

As far as I know in Windows Operating Systems we have Virtual Memory which is stored on the hard disk. Which drive is used for this purpose ? I have a service that uses a lot of memory so I would like to know whether there is enough disk space.

Rgds,

MK

Answer (score 0):

You can use vbscript then call this in your preferred language.  [See this reference for page file scripts](http://www.activexperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/adminscripts/disk/pagefiles/).